# session Logout problem in jsf

Tags: jsf

I am working on a web application and using framework jsf,hibernate and spring.

There are different kind of users in application.On the basis of user looged in type there i am enabling the link in menu for different user type.

Logout link in menu bar is provided to user once user is logged in.
i have written my logout.jsp page.

<%
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("../login/login.jsf"));
%>

even though after logout user is able to view the pages which should be displayed to specific type of users.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

The page is apparently been requested from the browser cache.

Disable it by adding a `javax.servlet.Filter` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` covering the dynamic pages like `*.jsf` and does the following in `doFilter()` method.

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

After call

```
session.invalidate();
```

add

```
request.logout();.
```

Method logout establish null as the value returned when getUserPrincipal, getRemoteUser, and getAuthType is called on the request.