# JSF logged out removed session

Tags: session, jsf, weblogic, login-control

I am developing a jsf based web application on Eclipse IDE. I am facing some problems regarding login and **logout** operations. The A.S is a Weblogic. I can successfully loggin in and logging out to the application, but following code is not destroying the session ...:

My logout function

```
public String logout() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContenter code hereext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
    request.getSession(true).invalidate();
    return ("logout");
}
```

Faces-Config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Home page for logging

```
<body>
<h:form id="Form">
        Hello<span style="color: ORANGE">
            #{profileController.profile.name}</span>


    <h:commandLink value="sign out" action="#{profileController.logout}" />
</h:form>
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Do not remove user session after logout.In this picture I tried to firefox back button and session not removed
![Session not removed]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ODvvH.png

Answer (score 1):

The page you see is most likely from the browser cache. You can disable the cache for certain or all of your pages. See this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4817088/620338) for details.

Comment: how to disable cache all of pages ?

Comment: How to disable cache Mr. Matt Handy ?

Comment: You don't need to remove the whole browser cache. You just have to ensure that _your pages_ will not be cached. Click on the link in my answer. There is a possible solution you can adapt for your purposes.

Comment: I have dont some visions for your suggest solution.But i try to do.Can u tell me more information.This link is a lot of content someone.But i dont unserstand..So sorry..Help me. I should write Filter class ?

Comment: Yes you need a filter. See the [tag wiki for servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) filters for more information.

Comment: Mr Matt generally it is have decided to other solution ? Such as simpler, easier ...